# Is it possible to make static class foreach enabled?

Tags: c#, foreach, static-class

Say I have a class with a list like:

```
static class Accounts
{
   public static List<Account> Items;
   ...
}
```

I there a way to make it foreach enabled so that I can do foreach without referencing the Items list like:

foreach(Account account in Accounts) ?

Comment: what is wrong with `foreach(Account item in Accounts.Items)` ?

Comment: Well nothing really, just an obsessive idea to make it prettier. Wanted to know if its possible?

Comment: One advice : don't use statics. If you had normal instance, it would be possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. Per section 10.1.1.3 of the C# 5.0 spec, static classes can't implement interfaces.

> A static class declaration is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> ...
>
> - A static class may not include a class-base specification (§10.1.4) and cannot explicitly specify a base class or a list of implemented interfaces. A static class implicitly inherits from type object.
>
> ...

And as such, there's no way to implement `IEnumerable`, which is how `foreach` works.

I explored options making use of the fact that `foreach` will look do a member lookup or `GetEnumerator` if no interfaces are found, but that also doesn't work, because the `expr` argument that `foreach` is expecting does not support a type-name, unfortunately.

The best alternative would be to make it *not* static, and follow a singleton pattern instead. That is, have a static property that is the only allowable instance of the class. But that won't clear away the need to read a property, so it won't really get you anything anyway.

If you're just looking to obscure the implementation (good call), you could make the property of type `IEnumerable<Account>`, then set it equal (wherever you do that) to a new `List<Account>`. Then you aren't allowing, by contract, other classes to modify the list, and you aren't coupling them to the implementation. Those are the main advantages of implementing `IEnumerable` for something like this, anyway. So that should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the list?

```
foreach (Account account in Accounts.Items)
```

If you want to implement this, you will need to inherit the [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface and implement it's behavior.

In my opinion, doing so would be more confusing than just using the list directly.

Comment: I have IEnumerable inherited actually but I want to make the class static.

Comment: @user1778306 Well you cannot inherit non-static fields to a static class.

Comment: @user1778306 See Mathew's answer, it is probably what you want to do in this case.